# UART Transmit DMA. no UART_IRQ_Handler call after transmit complete (it works in debug mode)

Tags: embedded, hal, stm32f4

So I'm trying to send some data using DMA via UART (so using `UART_Transmit_DMA()` function).
Looking at the source code it setups a callback for the dma transfer complete and calls `HAL_DMA_Start_IT()`. When the transfer finishes, `DMA_IRQ_Handler` is called and calling `HAL_DMA_IRQHandler()` it calls the callback that enables the TransferComplete interrupt.

This action should launch the `UART_IRQ_Handler()` but this doesn't happen! Even if the NVIC is set up properly.

The only way I found to launch is to call `__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart, UART_IT_TC)` before `UART_Transmit_DMA()`. But this is not enough, **the only way to make it works is to place a breakpoint at  `__HAL_UART_CLEAR_FLAG(huart, UART_FLAG_TC)`** (inside stm32f4xx_hal_uart.c) in this way the interrupt routines (DMA & UART_IRQ_Handler) are executed first then `__HAL_UART_CLEAR_FLAG(huart, UART_FLAG_TC)` is executed at the end.

Is this normal or I am doing something wrong?

**EDIT**:
Ok I discovered another think, I better understood the problem now.
Starting from the fact that `__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart, UART_IT_TC)` is useless in my case ( I don't need to enable the ITC bit in the register), there is always the same problem.

The DMA callback enables the ITC but meanwhile the TC status flag has been cleared so no interrupt fires. If I put a breakpoint before clearing the TC status flag, the ITC is set by the callback and the interrupt fires successfully!

What is the meaning of clearing this flag inside `UART_Transmit_DMA()`?

```c
/* Enable the UART transmit DMA stream */
tmp = (uint32_t *)&pData;
HAL_DMA_Start_IT(huart->hdmatx, *(uint32_t *)tmp, (uint32_t)&huart->Instance->DR, Size);

/* Clear the TC flag in the SR register by writing 0 to it */
__HAL_UART_CLEAR_FLAG(huart, UART_FLAG_TC); //<<<!!!--- why this?

/* Process Unlocked */
__HAL_UNLOCK(huart);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at more complete part of `HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA` (there is some more code, but it is only about variables initialization)

```
HAL_DMA_Start_IT(huart->hdmatx, *(uint32_t *)tmp, (uint32_t)&huart->Instance->DR, Size);

/* Clear the TC flag in the SR register by writing 0 to it */
__HAL_UART_CLEAR_FLAG(huart, UART_FLAG_TC);

/* Process Unlocked */
__HAL_UNLOCK(huart);

/* Enable the DMA transfer for transmit request by setting the DMAT bit
   in the UART CR3 register */
SET_BIT(huart->Instance->CR3, USART_CR3_DMAT);
```

`HAL_DMA_Start_IT` configures DMA transfer only, this function doesn't touch UART. At this point DMA is ready to serve requests from UART, but no requests are made since DMAT bit in the UART_CR3 register is not set yet, and no data is transfered.

`__HAL_UART_CLEAR_FLAG(husart, USART_FLAG_TC);` only clears the TC flag in the status register, it doesn't hinder further interrupt generation (remember, UART is not transmitting anything at this point), the interrupt is enabled in UART_CR1 register and fired when all data is sent to the line. Reason for the clear is simple and very general - before enabling the interrupt it's status (flag, that generates the interrupt) should be cleared, or it'll fire immediately. I don't know why they cleared in here and not in the callback right before enabling the TC interrupt, but it looks like developer's decision.

`SET_BIT(huart->Instance->CR3, USART_CR3_DMAT);` this line enables DMA requests from UART, and only after this call the transmission would start. And a bit later the TC interrupt could be generated.

In your case the `DMAT` might bit is already set before a call to `HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA`. Please provide all your code, related to the question - initialization and starting transfers. Without it only guesses can be made.